# If $\mu(X)<\infty$ then $f \in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int f_n \to \int f$ - An exercise question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Fix a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$. Suppose $\{f_n\} \subset L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Then I want to prove the following statement:

> If $\mu(X)<\infty$ then $f \in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int f_n \to \int f$.

In some lecture notes, the attempted solution is as follows (I rewrite it in my language):

Since $f_n \to f$ uniformly then there exists $N$ such that $\left\lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\right\rvert < 1$ for all $n \geq N$ and all $x \in X$. Therefore, $$\int \left\lvert f \right\rvert \leq \int \left\lvert f - f_N \right\rvert + \int  \left\lvert f_N \right\rvert \leq \int 1+ \int \left\lvert f_N \right\rvert = \mu(X) + \int \left\lvert f_N \right\rvert < \infty$$

so $f \in L^1$.

Then main point that I do not understand here is that, how can we say that $\mu(X) + \int \left\lvert f_N \right\rvert < \infty$? $\mu(X) < \infty$ by definition, however I couldn't see why $\int \left\lvert f_N \right\rvert < \infty$. Is this solution makes sense? If so, can anyone explain this? Thanks!

Comment: $f_N$ is integrable, isn't it?

Comment: $f_N\in L^1(\mu)$, isn't it?

Comment: Ah! Now I am complaining to write all this stuff. That is by definition. Many thanks! :)

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: it's even funny, that our comments with 8 seconds difference are equivalent, and still different :)

Comment: @John: since you are done so fast, what if $\mu(X) = \infty$?

Comment: Then I guess these conditions fail. I will try to construct counterexamples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\int_X f_n\,\mathrm d\mu-\int_X f\,\mathrm d\mu\right|\leqslant\int_X|f_n-f|\,\mathrm d\mu\leqslant\mu(X)\cdot\|f-f_n\|_\infty$$

Comment: There is a problem with this proof: one of the stated aims of the proof is to show that f is integrable over X... you have simply assumed this to be true here, as evidenced by the second integral on the left hand side of the first inequality.

Comment: Although, I suppose you were simply going off of oeda's legitimate proof for the integrabiity of f.  Very well, then.  Carry on.

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0):

Using again that
$$\vert f_n - f\vert < 1$$
for $n\ge N$,
$$|f_n|\le \vert f_n - f\vert + |f|\le 1 + |f|\in L^1$$
and we can apply the [Dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).