# Counterexamples to $\{f_n\} \subseteq L^1(\mu)$, $f_n \to f$ uniformly, $\mu(X) = \infty$ then $f \in L^1(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

When $\mu(X) < \infty$

$\{f_n\} \subseteq L^1(\mu)$, $f_n \to f$  uniformly, then $f \in L^1(\mu)$

is a true statement by [If $\mu(X)<\infty$ then $f \in L^1(\mu)$ and $\int f_n \to \int f$ - An exercise question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276029/if-mux-infty-then-f-in-l1-mu-and-int-f-n-to-int-f-an-exercise)

What if $\mu(X) = \infty$?

---

My first thought was to let $X = (0, \infty)$ under the Lebesgue measure, define $f_n = (\frac{1}{x})^{1 + 1/n}$ and argue that while for all $n$, $\int |f_n| < \infty$, $\int |\frac{1}{x}| = \infty$.

However, it is not the case that $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

---

Can someone propose a counter-example where $X = \mathbb{R}$ and the Lebesgue measure is used?

Answer (score 4):

Just take your favorite continuous non-$L^1$ function that vanishes at $\infty$, such as $\frac 1 x \chi_{\{x > 1\}}$, and cut it off on a large interval. You get a sequence such as

$$f_n(x) = \frac 1 x \chi_{\{1 < x < n\}}.$$